# Inserting data to MySQL table via PHP script - command line

Tags: php, mysql

I am new here and read other questions but couldn't find answer. I am trying to write a simple PHP script to insert new row into MySQL database.

I am using Ubuntu Server without GUI.  My script looks like that.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "books_test";

$polaczenie = mysqli_connect($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

if($polaczenie->connect_errno!=0)
{
  echo "Error\n";
}

else
{
  echo "Polaczono z baza\n";
  $SQL="INSERT INTO books VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Alicja w Krainie czarów', 'Carol Luis', 
            'England')";  

  if (@mysqli_query($SQL, $polaczenie)){
    echo "Nowy rekord dodany prawidlowo\n";
      }

  else{
    echo "Nie dodano nowego rekordu\n";

    }
}   ?>
```

It shows that the connection with database is OK but still it doesn't insert a row. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe you need to add columns names to your insert statement... some like this:

 insert into books('columnA','columnB') values ('A','B');

when the statement use the word values.

when not using values keyword you can use insert into books ('A','B'); statement.

Comment: did you check `mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`

Comment: And the link comes first not the SQL query `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link ,string $query )`

Comment: Add columns list in your query:
`INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)` then you can set only necessary columns

Answer (score 1):

Just change `mysqli_query($SQL, $polaczenie)` to `mysqli_query($polaczenie,$SQL)`

But try to use the object style only not the procedual style!!
And dont mix them, read here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: Hi. I was trying to use object oriented query as you suggest but it wasn't working. That is why I tried procedural way but it is also not working. The same goes for changing place of $polaczenie and $SQL

Comment: I am not sure whethe I am right but I added try and catch like this     try 
  {
    (@$polaczenie->query($SQL));
  }
 
   catch(Exception $e)
  {
   echo 'Message: '. $e->getMessage();
  }
and it is not working